# Capture only one thumbnail image from a video

Tags: java, image, video, xuggler

i am working to generate thumbnail images from a video. I am able to do it but i need only one thumbnail image from a video , but what i get is more than one images at different times of the video. I have used the following code to generate the thumbnails . Please suggest me what should i modify in the following code to get only one thumbnail from the middle portion of the video . The code i used is as follows ( I have used Xuggler ):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaListenerAdapter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.event.IVideoPictureEvent;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Global;

public class Main {

    public static final double SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 10;
    private static final String inputFilename = "D:\\k\\Knock On Wood Lesson.flv";
    private static final String outputFilePrefix = "D:\\pix\\";
// The video stream index, used to ensure we display frames from one and
// only one video stream from the media container.
    private static int mVideoStreamIndex = -1;
// Time of last frame write
    private static long mLastPtsWrite = Global.NO_PTS;
    public static final long MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES =
            (long) (Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFilename);
        // stipulate that we want BufferedImages created in BGR 24bit color space
        mediaReader.setBufferedImageTypeToGenerate(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        mediaReader.addListener(new ImageSnapListener());
        // read out the contents of the media file and
        // dispatch events to the attached listener
        while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null);
    }

    private static class ImageSnapListener extends MediaListenerAdapter {

        public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) {
            if (event.getStreamIndex() != mVideoStreamIndex) {
                // if the selected video stream id is not yet set, go ahead an
                // select this lucky video stream
                if (mVideoStreamIndex == -1) {
                    mVideoStreamIndex = event.getStreamIndex();
                } // no need to show frames from this video stream
                else {
                    return;
                }
            }
            // if uninitialized, back date mLastPtsWrite to get the very first frame
            if (mLastPtsWrite == Global.NO_PTS) {
                mLastPtsWrite = event.getTimeStamp() - MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;
            }
            // if it's time to write the next frame
            if (event.getTimeStamp() - mLastPtsWrite
                    >= MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES) {
                String outputFilename = dumpImageToFile(event.getImage());
                // indicate file written
                double seconds = ((double) event.getTimeStamp())
                        / Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND;
                System.out.printf("at elapsed time of %6.3f seconds wrote: %s\n",
                        seconds, outputFilename);
                // update last write time
                mLastPtsWrite += MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;
            }
        }

        private String dumpImageToFile(BufferedImage image) {
            try {
                String outputFilename = outputFilePrefix
                        + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(outputFilename));
                return outputFilename;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is all your code? Maybe im missing somthing but it looks like a list of import statements.

Answer (score 3):

**This is how you can.**

```
     public class ThumbsGenerator { 

       private static void processFrame(IVideoPicture picture, BufferedImage image) { 
              try { 

                    File file=new File("C:\\snapshot\thimbnailpic.png");//name of pic
                    ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);


            } catch (Exception e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
    } 


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,IOException { 

            String filename = "your_video.mp4";

            if (!IVideoResampler.isSupported(IVideoResampler.Feature.FEATURE_COLORSPACECONVERSION)) 
            throw new RuntimeException("you must install the GPL version of Xuggler (with IVideoResampler support) for this demo to work"); 


            IContainer container = IContainer.make(); 


            if (container.open(filename, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0) 
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("could not open file: " 
                                    + filename); 


            String seconds=container.getDuration()/(1000000*2)+""; // time of thumbnail 

            int numStreams = container.getNumStreams(); 

            // and iterate through the streams to find the first video stream 
            int videoStreamId = -1; 
            IStreamCoder videoCoder = null; 
            for (int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++) { 
                    // find the stream object 
                    IStream stream = container.getStream(i); 
                    // get the pre-configured decoder that can decode this stream; 
                    IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder(); 

                    if (coder.getCodecType() == ICodec.Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO) { 
                            videoStreamId = i; 
                            videoCoder = coder; 
                            break; 
                    } 
            } 

            if (videoStreamId == -1) 
                    throw new RuntimeException( 
                                    "could not find video stream in container: " + filename); 



            if (videoCoder.open() < 0) 
                    throw new RuntimeException( 
                                    "could not open video decoder for container: " + filename); 

            IVideoResampler resampler = null; 
            if (videoCoder.getPixelType() != IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24) { 


                    resampler = IVideoResampler.make(videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder 
                                    .getHeight(), IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24, videoCoder 
                                    .getWidth(), videoCoder.getHeight(), videoCoder 
                                    .getPixelType()); 
                    if (resampler == null) 
                            throw new RuntimeException( 
                                            "could not create color space resampler for: " 
                                            + filename); 
            } 


            IPacket packet = IPacket.make(); 


            IRational timeBase = container.getStream(videoStreamId).getTimeBase(); 


            System.out.println("Timebase " + timeBase.toString()); 


            long timeStampOffset = (timeBase.getDenominator() / timeBase.getNumerator()) 
                                    * Integer.parseInt(seconds); 
            System.out.println("TimeStampOffset " + timeStampOffset); 


            long target = container.getStartTime() + timeStampOffset; 


            container.seekKeyFrame(videoStreamId, target, 0); 

            boolean isFinished = false; 

            while(container.readNextPacket(packet) >= 0 && !isFinished ) { 




                    if (packet.getStreamIndex() == videoStreamId) { 


                            IVideoPicture picture = IVideoPicture.make(videoCoder 
                                            .getPixelType(), videoCoder.getWidth(), videoCoder 
                                            .getHeight()); 

                            int offset = 0; 
                            while (offset < packet.getSize()) { 


                                    int bytesDecoded = videoCoder.decodeVideo(picture, packet, 
                                                    offset); 
                                    if (bytesDecoded < 0) { 
                                            System.err.println("WARNING!!! got no data decoding " + 
                                                            "video in one packet"); 
                                    } 
                                    offset += bytesDecoded; 



                                    picture from 


                                    if (picture.isComplete()) { 

                                            IVideoPicture newPic = picture; 



                                            if (resampler != null) { 

                                                    newPic = IVideoPicture.make(resampler 
                                                                    .getOutputPixelFormat(), picture.getWidth(), 
                                                                    picture.getHeight()); 
                                                    if (resampler.resample(newPic, picture) < 0) 
                                                            throw new RuntimeException( 
                                                                            "could not resample video from: " 
                                                                            + filename); 
                                            } 

                                            if (newPic.getPixelType() != IPixelFormat.Type.BGR24) 
                                                    throw new RuntimeException( 
                                                                    "could not decode video as BGR 24 bit data in: " 
                                                                    + filename); 


                                            BufferedImage javaImage = Utils.videoPictureToImage(newPic); 


                                            processFrame(newPic, javaImage); 
                                            isFinished = true; 
                                    } 
                            } 
                    } 
            } 


            if (videoCoder != null) { 
                    videoCoder.close(); 
                    videoCoder = null; 
            } 
            if (container != null) { 
                    container.close(); 
                    container = null; 
            } 
    } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I found the same piece of tutorial code while playing with **Xuggler** today. The reason you are getting multiple thumbnails is due to the following line:

```
public static final double SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 10;
```

This variable specifies the number of seconds between calls to `dumpImageToFile`. So a frame thumbnail will be written at 0.00 seconds, at 10.00 seconds, at 20.00 seconds, and so on:

```
if (event.getTimeStamp() - mLastPtsWrite >= MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES)
```

To get a frame thumbnail from the middle of the video you can calculate the duration of the video using more **Xuggler** capability which I found in a tutorial at [JavaCodeGeeks](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/introduction-xuggler-video-manipulation.html). Then change your code in the `ImageSnapListener` to only write a single frame once the `IVideoPictureEvent` event timestamp exceeds the calculated mid point.

I hope that helps anyone who stumbles across this question.